# Python how can I print cp1258 vietnamese characters correctly?

Tags: python, encoding

How can I correctly print Vietnamese `cp1258` encoded characters in python 3? My terminal doesnt seem to be the issue as it will print the first print statement in my code correctly. I am trying to decode hex characters to vietnamese

Code:

```py
import binascii

data = 'tạm biệt'
print(data) # tạm biệt

a = binascii.hexlify(data.encode('cp1258', errors='backslashreplace'))
print(a) # b'745c75316561316d2062695c753165633774'
# if i dont use the error handler here, then I get a UnicodeEncodeError for \u1ea1

print(
    binascii.unhexlify(a).decode('cp1258') # t\u1ea1m bi\u1ec7t
)
```

Comment: Does simply `print(data)` not do what you want? This is really about how your system is configured - what's the system code page and do you have Python set up with the same configuration?

Comment: It's difficult to know from your example what you're trying to do and why. The UnicodeEncodeError means you have a character that simply doesn't exist in the character set `cp1258`.

Comment: What I am trying to do here is decode hex to vietnamese chars. Thats why the `print(data)` is simply a debug statement to make suer that my system is configured properly.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I am sure that character exists because `cp1258` is specific to vietnamese.

Comment: But if you look at the definition of [cp1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258) you won't find the `ạ`. The reason Unicode exists is because all earlier character sets were insufficient.

Comment: Ah.. hmm.. odd. because i saw [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) that `cp1258` was for vietnamese..

Comment: There were many older codepages that were intended for some languages but still did not encompass all of their usual character set (missing the rarer characters).

Comment: Yes, you guys are right. When I tested other vietnamese chars, it is working as expected. I guess my question now is how can i get `t\u1ea1m bi\u1ec7t` to print as `tạm biệt`?

Comment: My advice is to leave everything in Unicode and forget about other code pages. `print()` will automatically convert to what your output device can support.

Comment: Yeah I can do that @MarkRansom. But it still doesnt print `tạm biệt`, but prints `t\u1ea1m bi\u1ec7t` even if i remove all the encodings.

Comment: Your problem is that the `backslashreplace` parameter is converting those characters that aren't supported into multi-character sequences that are unrecoverable from that point forward. If your data isn't created through `encode` then you won't have that problem.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an omission in Python's support for [code page 1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258). The legacy codec does support Vietnamese by way of combining diacritics, but Python doesn't know how to convert Unicode to these combinations. I guess you will have to perform your own conversion.

As a first step, observe that `unicodedata.normalize('NFD', data)` splits the representation into a base character and a sequence of combining diacritics.

```py
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFD', data).encode('utf-8')
b'ta\xcc\xa3m bie\xcc\xa3\xcc\x82t'
>>> '{0:04x}'.format(ord(b'\xcc\xa3'.decode('utf-8')))
'0323'
```

So U+0323 is the combining Unicode diacritic for dot-under, and this correspondence *should* be known to the codec (the Wikipedia page I link to above shows the same Unicode character code for the CP1258 code point 0xF2).

I don't know enough about the target codec to tell you how to map these to CP1258, but if you are lucky, there is already *some sort of* mapping of these in the Python codec.

`iconv` on my Mojave MacOS seems to convert this without a hitch:

```sh
$ iconv -t cp1258 <<<'tạm biệt' | xxd
00000000: 7461 f26d 2062 69ea f274 0a              ta.m bi..t.
```

From this, it looks like the diacritic applies straightforwardly as a suffix -- `61` is `a`, and as noted above, `f2` is the combining diacritic to place a dot under the main glyph.

If you have a working `iconv`, a quick and dirty workaround might be to run it as a `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess

converted = subprocess.run(['iconv', '-t', 'cp1258'],
    input=data.encode('utf-8'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
```

If my understanding is correct, this should really be reported as a bug in Python. It should definitely know how to round-trip between this codec and Unicode if it wants to claim that it supports it.

Comment: Very well said!

Comment: I think you meant `'NFD'` and not `'NFC'`, but that still leaves you with an encoding problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, I noticed the same thing, brain fart. I expanded on the topic a bit while fixing it.

Comment: So it seems you've uncovered a flaw in the `cp1258` codec - I don't see any reason why a combining character in one character set can't be converted to a combining character in another as long as the conversion is officially defined.

Comment: @tripleee want to file a bug with python?

Comment: Feel free to report it. I had never paid any attention to this codec before today. It makes more sense for somebody who has some degree of involvement to act as the stakeholder. There's an [earlier bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue21081) abut a different codec where the informant basically says nobody in Vietnam actually uses cp1258.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Decoding with `unicode-escape` does the trick.

```py
import binascii

data = u'tạm biệt'
print(data) # tạm biệt

a = binascii.hexlify(data.encode('cp1258', errors='backslashreplace'))
print(a) # b'745c75316561316d2062695c753165633774'
# if i dont use the error handler here, then I get a UnicodeEncodeError for \u1ea1

print(
    binascii.unhexlify(a).decode('unicode-escape') # tạm biệt
)
```

Comment: This is just compensating for a problem of your own creation. It is not likely to help with the problem that originally brought you here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This answer just addresses one of the questions I asked in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the question is worth a revisit.

Windows-1258 uses a mix of precomposed and combining characters to support Vietnamese. All vowels are precomposed, all tones use non-spacing marks. So when converting from Windows-1258 to Unicode, the resultant Unicode string is unnormalised, i.e. it is neither NFC or NFD.

A straight conversion will throw errors:

```py
s = 'tạm biệt'
s.encode('Windows-1258')
```

produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/andrewc/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/encodings/cp1258.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ea1' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
encoding with 'Windows-1258' codec failed
```

To convert from Unicode to Windows-1258, it is necessary to prepossess the strings. Below, I create a set of bidirectional transliteration rules, then create an ICU Transliterator instance, then convert the text before encoding the text:

```py
import icu
rules = (":: NFD (NFC); "
    "a\u0306 <> \u0103; A\u0306 <> \u0102; a\u0323\u0306 <> \u0103\u0323; A\u0323\u0306 <> \u0102\u0323;"
    "a\u0302 <> \u00E2; A\u0302 <> \u00C2; a\u0323\u0302 <> \u00E2\u0323; A\u0323\u0302 <> \u00C2\u0323;"
    "e\u0302 <> \u00EA; E\u0302 <> \u00CA; e\u0323\u0302 <> \u00EA\u0323; E\u0323\u0302 <> \u00CA\u0323;"
    "o\u0302 <> \u00F4; O\u0302 <> \u00D4; o\u0323\u0302 <> \u00F4\u0323; O\u0323\u0302 <> \u00D4\u0323;"
    "o\u031B <> \u01A1; O\u031B <> \u01A0; u\u031B <> \u01B0; U\u031B <> \u01AF;"
)
tr = icu.Transliterator.createFromRules("custom_vn", rules, icu.UTransDirection.FORWARD)

s = 'tạm biệt'
t = tr.transliterate(s)
t.encode('Windows-1258')
# b'ta\xf2m bi\xea\xf2t'
```